# Python Matrix/Vector Operations

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with `shape = (2, 257)` and want to use each column which are vectors of `shape = (2,)`  to create an array with `shape = (2, 2)` for each column.

Previously I did this by selecting each column by iterating through my input array

```
import numpy as np

for counter in input    
    x = np.array([input[0][counter], input[1][counter]])
    y = np.conj(x)
    y = y.T

    E = x[:, None] * y
    corr_matr = np.where(self.iterator == 1, E, alpha * self.altes_E[counter] + (1 - alpha) * E)
    self.altes_E[counter] = corr_matr
```

However this is very slow and I would like to vectorize this calculation so in the end I will have an array containing my `E` variables for each column of my `input` variable. I tried to do so but I get broadcasting errors I am not able to solve.. So it will be great if someone helped me out!

`Self.iterator` will be removed and replaced by the first element of the new array containing all `E` arrays

My goal now is to have an Array which has the shape (257, 2, 2) and contains 257 2x2 `corr_matr` matrices. The n-th `corr_matr` depends on the n-1-th

`Self.altes_E` is this matrix I am looking for but I cant create it with my vectorized approach. Maybe you guys have an idea how I can create it vectorized without a for-loop.

```
Test data:
input = array([[ 3.94351315e-02+0.00000000e+00j, -1.50913336e-02+6.03795651e-04j,\n         1.99272113e-04-8.07005910e-04j, -4.67793985e-04+8.33903992e-04j,\n        -2.64236148e-03+2.77521785e-05j, -1.49792915e-03+7.36359583e-04j,\n         1.50533594e-03-6.15859179e-04j, -6.54810392e-05-5.01831397e-04j,\n        -1.01095434e-03-1.70553920e-04j,  5.81738784e-04+7.12800200e-04j,\n        -3.11310287e-04-9.01545559e-04j, -5.86002908e-05-9.55615603e-04j,\n         1.44156235e-04+1.09251279e-03j, -4.87454341e-04+8.03194960e-05j,\n         3.78562845e-04+1.29788540e-04j, -4.87558912e-04+6.55677040e-04j,\n        -4.87274113e-04-8.31101470e-04j,  8.16597471e-04+3.81774926e-04j,\n         5.89999582e-04-7.40645680e-05j, -7.03418446e-05-4.16067625e-04j,\n        -1.02284759e-03+2.56541860e-04j, -7.25162530e-05-2.12897828e-04j,\n         2.86242195e-04+2.15252463e-04j, -6.97098238e-04-5.35675945e-04j,\n         4.49257188e-04+4.96744002e-04j,  2.86015111e-04+9.92285825e-05j,\n        -6.63212048e-05-1.97287145e-04j, -4.96012767e-05+1.68083300e-04j,\n        -3.68913382e-04-1.76126405e-04j,  3.05618600e-04-2.13305860e-05j,\n        -1.22923172e-04-3.58717400e-04j, -3.92479536e-04+1.02063591e-03j,\n         6.45622389e-04-8.53094144e-04j, -3.14203107e-04+1.47936574e-04j,\n         1.54020776e-05-2.45868608e-05j,  2.78312174e-04+2.11224838e-04j,\n        -1.70668244e-04+4.57545662e-04j,  1.89143085e-04-1.62612861e-04j,\n        -5.05276967e-04-7.33565277e-04j,  3.87931183e-04+6.84968797e-05j,\n        -3.88693353e-04+3.29574348e-04j,  1.88775042e-05+3.06450544e-04j,\n        -1.02881416e-04-6.28814378e-04j,  1.50437664e-04-4.64790639e-05j,\n         6.80136794e-05+7.07755678e-04j,  4.29081846e-04-6.60769121e-06j,\n        -3.89883869e-05+9.94456323e-05j, -2.88405737e-04-3.90610565e-04j,\n         2.89706554e-04-4.61313935e-04j,  8.53534820e-05+3.45993148e-04j,\n        -6.48341994e-04+1.61728688e-05j,  7.08075756e-04+4.18876357e-04j,\n        -2.41676738e-04-6.57686042e-04j, -4.52960231e-05+4.69549856e-04j,\n        -2.98667220e-04+3.69428944e-04j,  3.09898762e-04-5.55573884e-04j,\n         3.16198618e-05-2.18262971e-04j, -2.43962041e-05+6.14800458e-04j,\n         1.22281179e-04-4.27259031e-05j, -2.02764807e-04-3.04080095e-04j,\n        -2.60131161e-05-2.72507038e-04j, -3.48411552e-04-1.65106382e-04j,\n         3.60262912e-04+1.15929180e-03j,  6.44188577e-04-6.57529271e-04j,\n        -6.64472633e-04+7.34788284e-05j, -2.53962823e-04-8.64577990e-05j,\n         4.12548109e-04-4.30493761e-04j, -3.89652217e-04+1.10427049e-03j,\n         2.19613546e-04-6.47350601e-04j, -3.01855256e-04-1.70512519e-04j,\n         3.52232474e-04-5.97253780e-04j, -2.46726574e-04+8.25901553e-05j,\n         5.01323354e-04+4.97268616e-04j, -3.87112186e-04+2.31773757e-04j,\n        -5.51833095e-04+5.28582216e-04j,  1.52037945e-04-9.87780746e-04j,\n         1.80951699e-04-1.64293165e-04j,  9.81853960e-04+8.24736454e-04j,\n        -3.08003998e-04+4.10959821e-05j, -7.18984896e-04+9.56216393e-05j,\n         9.23759625e-06-5.16799160e-04j,  3.62720586e-04-4.27438243e-04j,\n         4.54825689e-04+6.60654467e-04j, -8.45689094e-04+3.84855215e-04j,\n        -2.67177134e-05-7.42870583e-04j, -1.92531972e-04-3.02859614e-04j,\n         7.90923909e-04+2.13245532e-04j, -7.46436347e-04+4.59160357e-04j,\n         2.42516064e-04+5.79452623e-04j,  2.76445921e-04-1.07193028e-03j,\n        -5.72620393e-04+1.96574790e-04j,  1.34058726e-03+2.34585361e-04j,\n        -3.57420647e-04-1.70451007e-04j, -2.82518121e-04+2.07459060e-04j,\n        -4.28715245e-05-3.11639838e-04j, -2.31994207e-04-3.50393413e-04j,\n         1.79812526e-04+9.46405559e-06j,  6.45826858e-06-7.27244722e-05j,\n        -6.54773349e-04+9.59387600e-04j,  3.84335152e-04-2.72657471e-04j,\n        -4.87276832e-04-3.96541032e-04j,  6.77017368e-04+4.47778225e-04j,\n         4.45890499e-04+1.29559357e-04j, -6.51094304e-04+1.86624435e-04j,\n         3.98953747e-05-4.33256129e-04j, -2.22111375e-04-2.04651458e-04j,\n         7.55794351e-04-5.85769035e-04j, -3.94789819e-04+1.04401607e-03j,\n        -1.58222133e-04+1.11208833e-05j,  9.23486664e-05-7.75775861e-04j,\n        -3.43146772e-04+1.17239880e-04j,  2.84564728e-04+6.11844429e-06j,\n         4.70805410e-04+3.47810038e-04j,  1.69658330e-04-6.84370728e-06j,\n        -5.22356227e-04+6.50334373e-04j, -1.73679813e-04+3.63334974e-05j,\n         4.98834691e-04-1.01761885e-03j,  5.87157344e-04+1.20334407e-04j,\n        -9.03141283e-04+5.43231194e-04j,  2.12604011e-04+4.25936737e-05j,\n         1.20421975e-04+1.99248114e-04j,  1.36291525e-04-1.74378105e-04j,\n        -3.22569755e-04-3.90555480e-04j, -8.56585373e-04-1.36390458e-05j,\n         8.21771053e-04+5.11195915e-04j, -1.32706058e-04-6.24514006e-05j,\n        -5.38444724e-04-7.24478095e-04j,  1.28496700e-03+2.93993678e-05j,\n        -6.10961533e-04+1.10329922e-04j, -3.67753624e-04+2.46454903e-04j,\n        -1.97998194e-04+4.12632455e-04j,  4.80604477e-04-2.31270841e-04j,\n         1.92777568e-05-4.07627748e-04j,  2.86666234e-04+7.01966268e-05j,\n         1.15379387e-04-1.33773849e-04j, -3.17265283e-04+5.00725722e-04j,\n         1.36599939e-04-6.75427006e-04j,  6.37731351e-05+7.04635115e-04j,\n        -1.96653870e-04+3.25483834e-04j, -5.86921673e-04-1.23419379e-03j,\n         3.14143574e-04+1.00360594e-04j,  3.31560079e-04+1.07206559e-03j,\n         4.92924636e-05-5.68876368e-04j, -8.41042140e-04+3.22939688e-04j,\n         5.49575067e-04-5.15098419e-05j, -3.93180240e-04-4.42074142e-05j,\n         5.60555298e-04-2.85327349e-04j, -2.38831244e-04+1.91581065e-05j,\n        -7.45519046e-05+1.27549869e-04j, -5.89318659e-05-4.21902661e-04j,\n         3.75275146e-04+1.82785513e-05j, -2.34356665e-04+4.60409956e-04j,\n        -1.92879655e-04+2.25686712e-05j,  2.29916609e-04-3.98052727e-04j,\n         1.14636467e-04+3.40506254e-04j,  3.66346397e-04+4.71324904e-05j,\n        -3.50054041e-04-5.13589144e-04j, -2.54987713e-04+1.99572441e-04j,\n         5.45736142e-07-5.96936864e-05j, -1.24422570e-04+9.28100584e-05j,\n        -3.07471848e-04-4.81938971e-05j,  8.54350904e-04+8.01221802e-05j,\n        -1.36143168e-03+1.05957395e-04j,  4.67515499e-04+1.18207109e-04j,\n         2.22224539e-04-7.87005141e-04j,  2.06836573e-04+7.33415318e-04j,\n         4.11857186e-05-2.78641304e-04j,  8.46935368e-05+2.47412699e-05j,\n         9.63134514e-05-6.25919599e-04j, -1.74852058e-04+6.83190116e-04j,\n         5.17474224e-05-2.10492739e-05j,  5.02637722e-05+8.55532060e-06j,\n        -1.48067521e-04+1.27482971e-04j, -3.17709988e-04-3.19972013e-04j,\n         7.93806547e-04+7.24172271e-04j,  3.71753847e-04-2.96357705e-04j,\n        -7.16045744e-04-2.45445209e-04j,  1.85488700e-04-7.80975779e-05j,\n        -6.33931296e-04-3.79990485e-04j,  4.23058885e-04+5.71413970e-04j,\n        -1.96111954e-04-1.64805179e-04j, -2.39387453e-04+4.67926668e-04j,\n         4.48049475e-04-4.39783397e-04j, -4.57884754e-04-8.64764107e-05j,\n         2.36198689e-04-1.81618919e-04j, -3.98041496e-04+5.49284505e-04j,\n         7.71543104e-04+2.33418707e-04j, -5.37125816e-04-1.39968077e-04j,\n         1.21667266e-04+2.94272358e-05j, -4.22621149e-05-4.03145881e-04j,\n         5.15855772e-04+6.12452186e-05j, -1.75597310e-04+3.06332086e-04j,\n         9.80239412e-05-5.22006358e-04j, -3.91105404e-04+7.24365490e-04j,\n         5.41880105e-04-6.62486843e-04j, -1.44683949e-04+2.83522226e-04j,\n        -1.91702886e-04+1.31554681e-04j,  5.24558737e-05-1.08982522e-04j,\n         6.74327223e-04+1.10659354e-04j, -5.79971252e-04+1.77968960e-04j,\n        -2.51067236e-04-1.07853197e-04j,  3.11939498e-04-1.38577070e-04j,\n        -6.04476470e-05+8.52540539e-05j,  1.34265204e-04+8.21556997e-04j,\n        -1.17370999e-04-7.91857871e-04j,  2.79181388e-04-7.31803351e-04j,\n        -6.90453886e-04+7.46784829e-04j, -1.16164963e-04-4.57167257e-04j,\n        -4.69417951e-04-4.41735735e-04j,  1.35998487e-05+1.12007021e-03j,\n         3.29877562e-04+1.48284571e-04j,  5.83769268e-04+2.49004599e-04j,\n        -7.52982150e-04-1.68075249e-03j, -3.38846404e-04+9.63951937e-04j,\n         3.55617024e-04-1.27152987e-04j,  8.13345170e-04-4.35530692e-04j,\n         2.21017421e-04+3.81957629e-04j, -2.29169840e-04+4.31749297e-04j,\n        -3.49092860e-04-5.49892781e-04j,  1.47060146e-05-4.94382810e-04j,\n         8.50208905e-04+7.47663086e-05j, -1.45781683e-04+3.05060633e-04j,\n        -5.68202031e-04+2.25181950e-04j, -6.70225923e-05-4.04705073e-04j,\n         5.49901664e-04+1.00974501e-03j,  1.09107837e-05-4.09919474e-04j,\n        -7.08992001e-04-6.93567150e-04j,  2.38546368e-05+3.33138967e-04j,\n         6.59087722e-04+4.15920176e-04j, -9.24723091e-04+5.72433162e-04j,\n         3.16802067e-04-1.97599886e-04j,  9.59921563e-04-7.20312263e-04j,\n        -2.04590275e-04-7.58383004e-04j, -9.83521376e-04+1.39303955e-03j,\n         1.00191560e-03-1.06808718e-03j, -1.44975474e-04+2.10013067e-04j,\n         1.57355072e-04-8.06148227e-05j, -9.77899528e-04+1.01124440e-03j,\n         1.40629188e-04+3.07843307e-04j,  4.58437822e-04-1.54270986e-03j,\n        -3.58655124e-06+3.05346109e-04j, -8.51095471e-04+9.50186675e-04j,\n         6.49841806e-04-3.69990669e-04j, -2.42669267e-04+1.97887318e-04j,\n         1.08560919e-03-5.57172096e-04j, -1.38075404e-03+3.06128065e-04j,\n        -2.99248592e-04-1.96865567e-04j,  4.34882427e-04+6.50054051e-05j,\n         1.09891678e-03+1.84768495e-04j, -7.36401037e-04-1.54611504e-03j,\n         1.95455637e-04+1.59373547e-03j, -1.65580093e-04-1.90926799e-04j,\n        -1.13688576e-04+4.12506434e-04j,  1.12544155e-03+4.77414267e-04j,\n        -1.31365139e-03-1.41451042e-03j,  5.79908017e-04+1.48045447e-04j,\n        -4.82300426e-04+0.00000000e+00j],\n       [ 3.94302788e-02+0.00000000e+00j, -1.50769610e-02+6.62688618e-04j,\n         1.63792293e-04-9.09965691e-04j, -4.20457549e-04+7.67888474e-04j,\n        -2.62611773e-03+1.79287284e-04j, -1.39992458e-03+8.62646142e-04j,\n         1.43622367e-03-8.15390156e-04j, -1.32725278e-04-5.22439730e-04j,\n        -1.02788776e-03-2.84542025e-05j,  7.04202642e-04+5.75840478e-04j,\n        -4.85970329e-04-8.42626503e-04j, -2.85902831e-04-9.33336830e-04j,\n         3.85726455e-04+1.01063584e-03j, -4.54619102e-04+1.89852072e-04j,\n         3.96938522e-04+4.87940712e-06j, -2.64396836e-04+7.56253750e-04j,\n        -7.20372356e-04-6.38146395e-04j,  8.97949930e-04+7.69071706e-05j,\n         5.23039447e-04-3.00850918e-04j, -2.30101044e-04-3.83685318e-04j,\n        -8.45559655e-04+6.25181058e-04j, -1.55582013e-04-1.67400948e-04j,\n         3.48307983e-04+6.57074044e-05j, -8.67179548e-04-1.65800957e-04j,\n         6.26144481e-04+2.31985901e-04j,  2.96950721e-04-5.87318674e-05j,\n        -1.59847453e-04-1.45575757e-04j,  4.17422830e-05+1.62311722e-04j,\n        -4.06935839e-04+4.60837714e-05j,  2.40112226e-04-1.88702128e-04j,\n        -3.12380034e-04-2.25416888e-04j,  2.83110337e-04+1.05608322e-03j,\n         1.69140411e-06-1.07341915e-03j, -1.61321781e-04+3.08879494e-04j,\n        -7.12735790e-06-2.89430707e-05j,  3.44852190e-04-2.42375302e-05j,\n         1.77649387e-04+4.46179235e-04j,  3.00653183e-05-2.58839835e-04j,\n        -8.75480076e-04-1.78086957e-04j,  3.15614668e-04-2.23862597e-04j,\n        -3.28856251e-05+5.09215677e-04j,  2.42580737e-04+1.91265064e-04j,\n        -5.38095552e-04-3.36387834e-04j,  5.89000296e-05-1.38800403e-04j,\n         5.93041602e-04+3.91920304e-04j,  2.58312359e-04-3.52047888e-04j,\n         5.41664911e-05+7.84828629e-05j, -4.87040484e-04+2.00465143e-07j,\n        -2.24098958e-04-5.00037983e-04j,  3.25842394e-04+1.16315659e-04j,\n        -3.33712131e-04+5.56801846e-04j,  7.20763407e-04-3.98413351e-04j,\n        -6.98367513e-04-1.21573550e-04j,  3.84986333e-04+2.61687346e-04j,\n         1.91783081e-04+4.26843301e-04j, -3.61446144e-04-5.30072060e-04j,\n        -1.90875135e-04-1.22069126e-04j,  5.47142772e-04+2.66855906e-04j,\n         4.08724905e-06-1.39431456e-04j, -3.61842034e-04+7.01928105e-05j,\n        -2.68947677e-04-7.08310314e-05j, -2.73181365e-04+2.79827782e-04j,\n         1.21452700e-03+1.36751774e-05j, -4.48800651e-04-8.19776275e-04j,\n        -1.19266297e-04+6.53314340e-04j, -1.48156234e-04+2.20506208e-04j,\n        -3.25802814e-04-5.00083015e-04j,  9.93835264e-04+6.10726403e-04j,\n        -5.92139594e-04-3.50046309e-04j, -2.20551315e-04+2.66541088e-04j,\n        -5.38101746e-04-4.33232244e-04j,  4.53140432e-05+2.67048105e-04j,\n         5.45584100e-04-4.36233554e-04j,  1.89055956e-04+4.05146241e-04j,\n         4.91230583e-04+5.80214622e-04j, -9.70303336e-04-2.07957665e-04j,\n        -1.54105042e-04-1.78764985e-04j,  8.29454691e-04-9.70980630e-04j,\n         2.93041276e-05+2.99636023e-04j,  1.11761881e-04+7.06579832e-04j,\n        -5.13429489e-04+1.03407490e-05j, -4.51280720e-04-3.28230045e-04j,\n         6.09306297e-04-5.08877271e-04j,  4.69052361e-04+7.90693011e-04j,\n        -7.29652303e-04+1.16791352e-04j, -2.63583592e-04+2.40084959e-04j,\n         7.80339281e-05-8.09166755e-04j,  5.91733367e-04+6.46003586e-04j,\n         5.18742468e-04-3.69670376e-04j, -1.10819540e-03-2.98322967e-05j,\n         3.35961109e-04+5.08219023e-04j, -1.37905601e-04-1.35428372e-03j,\n        -7.54841905e-05+3.93744885e-04j,  2.75316936e-04+2.05765280e-04j,\n        -2.85925096e-04+1.42533512e-04j, -2.49244553e-04+3.44507517e-04j,\n        -5.49966896e-05-1.61934566e-04j, -6.94024634e-05+3.21277311e-05j,\n         1.14427279e-03+2.14503629e-04j, -4.06256577e-04-2.42573698e-04j,\n        -1.37008788e-04+6.09181906e-04j,  9.41131852e-05-8.08853747e-04j,\n        -1.05763981e-04-4.56058417e-04j,  4.74122378e-04+4.69608012e-04j,\n        -3.95122830e-04+1.79715038e-04j, -5.41657307e-05+2.94641051e-04j,\n        -8.99698699e-04-3.08409334e-04j,  1.08313369e-03-2.52154929e-04j,\n         9.61555026e-05+1.16751009e-04j, -6.78396810e-04+3.85853518e-04j,\n         3.08973305e-04+2.04145634e-04j, -1.66564595e-04-2.23731139e-04j,\n        -3.64032556e-05-5.80136045e-04j, -1.25077116e-04-1.17649763e-04j,\n         8.22473217e-04-5.10403627e-05j,  1.35846968e-04+9.04349589e-05j,\n        -1.08069909e-03+3.56424784e-04j, -3.42539982e-04-4.83310914e-04j,\n         1.02127798e-03+2.27836680e-04j, -1.38094505e-04-1.76668123e-04j,\n         2.64921676e-05-2.31094625e-04j, -2.30827528e-04+4.76342119e-05j,\n         1.46863589e-07+5.09299510e-04j,  6.74095347e-04+5.26744232e-04j,\n        -3.63377125e-04-9.05099052e-04j,  6.26177364e-05+1.23244300e-04j,\n         4.31863072e-05+8.96514097e-04j, -1.06310512e-03-7.14346108e-04j,\n         5.75517243e-04+2.35967322e-04j,  4.41244980e-04-2.65860383e-05j,\n         3.70694639e-04-2.71684200e-04j, -5.39649217e-04-2.89578543e-05j,\n        -2.05237670e-04+3.55566693e-04j, -2.29304581e-04-1.82601791e-04j,\n        -1.63278707e-04+8.28089685e-05j,  4.85237610e-04-3.27131430e-04j,\n        -3.85198889e-04+5.78130634e-04j,  1.91039368e-04-6.73331290e-04j,\n         2.83290401e-04-2.36600115e-04j,  1.56155251e-04+1.35530242e-03j,\n        -2.58546407e-04-1.92172329e-04j, -1.64289988e-05-1.12061403e-03j,\n        -2.06761243e-04+5.39404115e-04j,  8.90146217e-04-1.10273389e-04j,\n        -5.53419489e-04-8.01172163e-05j,  3.69800922e-04+1.19385537e-04j,\n        -6.06753749e-04+1.74073233e-04j,  2.37762330e-04+2.21509768e-05j,\n         9.04367392e-05-1.17178154e-04j,  6.65735029e-06+4.23161474e-04j,\n        -3.66355661e-04-5.69644277e-05j,  2.72752455e-04-4.36970254e-04j,\n         1.89332418e-04-1.28477791e-05j, -2.48450704e-04+3.85021186e-04j,\n        -1.06569421e-04-3.41965661e-04j, -3.70428389e-04-4.26724302e-05j,\n         3.58595638e-04+5.14301117e-04j,  2.51269109e-04-2.08539926e-04j,\n         4.88939967e-06+5.71210855e-05j,  1.18578623e-04-1.05802288e-04j,\n         3.11344492e-04+1.01891390e-05j, -8.56978432e-04+1.74893270e-05j,\n         1.33232876e-03-2.98487141e-04j, -4.85805120e-04-5.94291833e-05j,\n        -7.76562206e-05+8.03680105e-04j, -3.43743448e-04-6.84465578e-04j,\n         1.92205105e-05+2.78271830e-04j, -8.62407096e-05-6.06097609e-06j,\n         7.51468262e-05+6.27872523e-04j, -1.25139166e-05-7.07494831e-04j,\n        -4.26531031e-05+3.33935842e-05j, -4.93983638e-05+6.62065104e-06j,\n         9.65211897e-05-1.71035129e-04j,  4.09508943e-04+1.81017834e-04j,\n        -1.00836515e-03-3.78649449e-04j, -2.28902765e-04+4.29769144e-04j,\n         7.55644169e-04-6.15984149e-05j, -1.31806876e-04+1.50093610e-04j,\n         7.41534101e-04+5.25070731e-05j, -6.37489984e-04-3.17623167e-04j,\n         2.50510928e-04+4.72741634e-05j, -3.12101871e-05-5.30198666e-04j,\n        -1.61833058e-04+6.04663509e-04j,  4.33069517e-04-1.76875910e-04j,\n        -9.68597935e-05+2.72233313e-04j,  1.29069366e-05-6.86698274e-04j,\n        -7.70844850e-04+2.59679250e-04j,  5.06334114e-04-2.08281614e-04j,\n        -1.23040807e-04+4.96912636e-05j,  2.81721303e-04+2.82239777e-04j,\n        -4.32856798e-04+2.85045100e-04j, -7.18904719e-05-3.42817657e-04j,\n         2.82159126e-04+4.51272457e-04j, -2.22012038e-04-7.93265681e-04j,\n         8.25420573e-05+8.53400594e-04j, -1.00706437e-04-2.98939601e-04j,\n         3.14683041e-05-2.27519261e-04j,  4.36941077e-05+1.13381143e-04j,\n        -5.18682202e-04+4.48501226e-04j,  2.30610517e-04-5.52246756e-04j,\n         2.34490912e-04-1.26264973e-04j, -7.97095177e-05+3.35952614e-04j,\n        -3.45318332e-05-9.44128409e-05j, -7.57633937e-04-3.43506355e-04j,\n         7.20500401e-04+3.51295162e-04j,  4.74556384e-04+6.27668922e-04j,\n        -2.81101536e-04-9.78262731e-04j,  4.46874372e-04+1.24837907e-04j,\n         6.05163789e-04-2.12023275e-04j, -1.01407397e-03-5.16929477e-04j,\n        -2.98164906e-04+2.33126469e-04j, -4.86355494e-04+4.33123201e-04j,\n         1.83462356e-03-7.71867376e-07j, -7.69209261e-04-7.01104884e-04j,\n        -3.18641790e-05+3.73050143e-04j,  1.15613125e-04+9.09600948e-04j,\n        -4.28446346e-04+7.86494004e-05j, -3.34852105e-04-3.47817544e-04j,\n         6.26099520e-04-1.68044497e-04j,  4.68369045e-04+1.42514209e-04j,\n        -2.83908873e-04+7.92399750e-04j, -2.49184244e-04-2.18710226e-04j,\n        -9.19001071e-05-6.04839544e-04j,  4.08264053e-04+9.93217421e-06j,\n        -1.08943196e-03+3.64046481e-04j,  4.09723216e-04+8.49350013e-05j,\n         7.86130478e-04-6.09249721e-04j, -3.38645074e-04-2.27244838e-05j,\n        -4.77324227e-04+6.16456017e-04j, -5.01373021e-04-9.55310274e-04j,\n         1.70573740e-04+3.42094097e-04j,  6.89184712e-04+9.91871858e-04j,\n         7.74817539e-04-2.00708515e-04j, -1.39524815e-03-9.81590142e-04j,\n         1.09255944e-03+9.77000557e-04j, -2.06580095e-04-1.44088734e-04j,\n         1.00169291e-04+1.44579525e-04j, -1.08783213e-03-8.86595885e-04j,\n        -2.96315620e-04+1.88823864e-04j,  1.58771473e-03+2.66780661e-04j,\n        -2.99713732e-04+3.14700680e-05j, -1.08078974e-03-6.78289646e-04j,\n         4.79116024e-04+5.81652824e-04j, -2.43603471e-04-1.88258714e-04j,\n         7.93634703e-04+9.36679925e-04j, -6.29229943e-04-1.26267628e-03j,\n         9.93210429e-05-3.33132766e-04j,  5.00382390e-05+4.41575210e-04j,\n         1.61111886e-04+1.10747772e-03j,  1.23195666e-03-1.20419700e-03j,\n        -1.43246313e-03+7.18458426e-04j,  1.23366572e-04-2.18045537e-04j,\n        -4.21981246e-04+5.80438962e-05j,  2.37621151e-05+1.23103317e-03j,\n         7.49466857e-04-1.79312642e-03j,  1.24531095e-04+4.69038221e-04j,\n        -8.82536309e-04+0.00000000e+00j]])

self.altes_E = np.zeros((257, 2, 2), dtype = complex)
alpha = 0.8
```

Comment: Could you  please describe all variables and possible write some test data?

Comment: test data added

Comment: Given your data, the for-loop gives lots of different errors. I am trying to understand the logic of it

Comment: yeah it might have not been the best idea to give just a snippet... The whole code is within two classes and one is reading an audio file which is generating this data. Maybe I will ask a new question containing everything..